# Как переключить класс только к одному html элементу в Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Помогите пожалуйста с задачей, буду очень благодарен!

постановка задачи:

1) Есть  template

```
<ul>
 <li v-bind:class="someClass">item01
 <button v-on:click="somefunction">Toggle single class</button>
</li>
 <li v-bind:class="someClass">item02
 <button v-on:click="somefunction">Toggle single class</button>
</li>
 <li v-bind:class="someClass">item03
 <button v-on:click="somefunction">Toggle single class</button>
</li>
</ul>
```

2) есть скрипт для управления изменениями в истинностью классах

```
export default {
    data(){
      return {
        someClass: false
      }
    },
    computed:{
      somefunction(){
          return this.someClass=!this.someClass;
      }
    }
}
```

3. Есть стили

   .someClass {
     background: red;
   }
4. Описание проблемы - При клике на кнопку "Toggle single class for first item", я ожиданию, что ТОЛЬКО для `<li v-bind:class="someClass">item01</li>` появиться фон с красным цветом.  Что я вижу - стили применяются ко все списку

   item01
  item02
  item03
5. Отсюда вытекает Вопрос - подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так, чтобы при клике на кнопку "Toggle single class for first item", применялся стиль только для данного айтема item01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно оформить шаблон вот так:

```
<ul v-for="(item, index) in items">
  <li v-bind:class="{someClass: index===currentIndex}">{{item}}
    <button v-on:click="currentIndex = index">Toggle single class</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

В массив items поместите названия пунктов списка, currentIndex добавьте в data и  все должно заработать по вашему сценарию.

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Помогло)